# How to deactivate headphone's buttons

Tags: headphones, headphone-jack

I think my headphone or phone jack broke, and if I move the jack a bit, somehow the headphones activate the google assistant or pause the music, so this is from the button.

Can I deactivate it on a non rooted Huawei P8Lite (Android 6.0)

Answer (score 3):

Software wise: HeadsetBlocker & Wizdroid both attempt to block headphone buttons. However both are very outdated. Can install and try.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.idunnolol.headsetblocker&hl=en
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yifandroid.wizdroids&hl=en

Hardware wise: You can try a 4 pole to 3 pole adapter to remove the microphone (I am not positive this will work)

[https://www.amazon.com/LEMENG-Female-Headset-Extension-Cable-2Pack/dp/B01LRWO9GU/ref=sr_1_6?ie=UTF8&qid=1510759624&sr=8-6&keywords=3+pole+adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01LRWO9GU)

Comment: I downloaded the WizDroid app, I hope it's going to work, i'll update in the next days.  And about the adapter, I won't try anyway beacuse I can't, Amazon is not in my area, but I'll search for one if the app won't work

Comment: +1 for hardware and software fix

Comment: Wizdroid isn't working and tge other app is not compatible :(

Answer (score 0):

This solution certainly won't work for everyone, but if your headphones happen to have a removable cable: trying turning it upside down (plugging the phone end into the headphones and vice versa). With my particular cable this disables the controls.